# Why isn't .focus() triggered when I open my modal?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to open a modal and then have it focus on the textarea it isn't working. Was wondering is anyone could help me. I'm sure it has something to do with the execution but I'm just not sure exactly what it is. Here is some code:

```js
$('.reportButton').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $($this).siblings('.reportModal').fadeIn();
        $($this).siblings('.reportModal textarea').focus();
    }, 100);
});

$(window).on('click', function(e) {
    if ($('.reportModal').is(':visible') && $(e.target).closest('.reportModalContent').length === 0) {
        $('.reportModal').fadeOut(); // Whichever the opened one is... Close them all!
    }
});

$('.closeReportModal').click(function(){
    //$('#myModal').css({'display':'none'});
    $(this).closest('.reportModal').fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
        <button class="reportButton">Report</button>
        <div class="reportModal">
            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="reportModalContent">
            <form action="/report/" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="">
              <div class="layer">
                <div class="report-header"><h2>
                    Report content
                </h2></div>
                <div class="closeReportModal" class="">&times;</div>
              </div>
              <hr>
              <div class="layer-2">
                  <dl>
                      <dt>
                        Report reason:
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
    
                        <textarea name="body" value=""></textarea>
    
                      </dd>
                  </dl>
              </div>
              <hr>
              <div class="layer-3">
                  <dl>
                      <dt>
    
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
                          <button type="submit" class="report">Report</button>
                      </dd>
                  </dl>
              </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Thank you I appreciate your help.

Comment: Use `$($this).siblings('.reportModal').find('textarea').focus();` and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you it does! Thank you! May I ask if you use React, or Vue? and which do you prefer?

Comment: I have not use them sorry so i cannot suggest . :) .